# Diferencias entre == y === (comparaciones en JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, comparaciones

Siempre he visto que en `JavaScript` hay:

- asignaciones `=`
- comparaciones `==` y `===`

Creo entender que `==` hace algo parecido a comparar el valor de la variable y el `===` también compara el tipo (como un equals de java).

**¿Alguien podría confirmarme este punto y extenderlo?**. Soy javero y el no tipado de javascript a veces me encanta y otras lo odio.

---

¿Cuál es la manera correcta en javascript de comparar `undefined`, `null` y otros valores por defecto?

```
variable == null
variable === null
```

¿**`undefined`** se usa como cadena de texto o como palabra clave? ¿Cual de las siguientes comparaciones es la correcta para un elemento `html` sin `value`? (por ejemplo un label sin contenido)

```
variable == "undefined"
variable === "undefined"
variable == undefined
variable === undefined
```

Comment: asociación: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/

Comment: asociación: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Los operadores `===` y `!==` son los operadores de comparación *estricta*. Esto significa que si los operandos tienen tipos diferentes, no son iguales. Por ejemplo,

```
1 === "1" // false
1 !== "1"  // true
null === undefined // false
```

Los operadores `==` y `!=` son los operadores de comparación *relajada*. Es decir, si los operandos tienen tipos diferentes, JavaScript trata de convertirlos para que fueran comparables. Por ejemplo,

```
1 == "1" // true
1 != "1" // false
null == undefined // true
```

Vale mencionar que el operador `==` no es [transitivo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaci%C3%B3n_transitiva), al contrario que `===`.

```
"0" == 0 // true
0 == ""  // true
"0" == ""// false
```

No es muy fácil recordar todas las reglas de la comparación relajada, y a veces funciona en una manera contraintuitiva. Por eso, yo recomiendo usar `===` en vez de `==`.

No recuerdo todos los pequeños detalles del operador `==`, entonces echemos un vistazo a la [especificación, punto 11.9.3:](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3)

> ## El algoritmo de la comparación de igualdad abstracta
>
> La comparación *x == y*, donde *x* e *y* son valores, regresa *true* o *false*. Esta comparación se realiza de la siguiente manera:
>
> 1. Si *Type(x)* y *Type(y)* son los mismos,
>
>    1. Si *Type(x)* es *Undefined*, regresa *true*.
>    2. Si *Type(x)* es *Null*, regresa *true*.
>    3. Si *Type(x)* es *Number*,
>
>       1. Si *x* es *NaN*, regresa *false*.
>       2. Si *y* es *NaN*, regresa *false*.
>       3. Si *x* es el mismo valor de *Number* que *y*, regresa *true*.
>       4. Si *x* es *+0* e *y* es *−0*, regresa *true*.
>       5. Si *x* es *-0* e *y* es *+0*, regresa *true*.
>       6. Regresa *false*.
>    4. Si *Type(x)* es *String*, regresa *true* si *x* e *y* son exactamente la misma secuencia de caracteres (con la misma longitud y los mismos caracteres en las posiciones correspondientes). En el caso contrario, regresa *false*.
>    5. Si *Type(x)* es *Boolean*, regresa *true*, si *x* e *y* ambos son *true* o ambos son *false*. En el caso contrario, regresa *false*.
>    6. Regresa *true* si *x* e *y* refieren al mismo objeto. En el caso contrario, regresa *false*.
> 2. Si *x* es *null* e *y* es *undefined*, regresa *true*.
> 3. Si *x* es *undefined* e *y* es *null*, regresa *true*.
> 4. Si *Type(x)* es *Number* y *Type(y)* es *String*,
>      regresa el resultado de la comparación *x == ToNumber(y)*.
> 5. Si *Type(x)* es *String* y *Type(y)* es *Number*,
>      regresa el resultado de la comparación *ToNumber(x) == y*.
> 6. Si *Type(x)* es *Boolean*, regresa el resultado de la comparación *ToNumber(x) == y*.
> 7. Si *Type(y)* es *Boolean*, regresa el resultado de la comparación *x == ToNumber(y)*.
> 8. Si *Type(x)* es *String* o *Number*, y *Type(y)* es *Object*,
>      regresa el resultado de la comparación *x == ToPrimitive(y)*.
> 9. Si *Type(x)* es *Object* y *Type(y)* es *String* o *Number*,
>      regresa el resultado de la comparación *ToPrimitive(x) == y*.
> 10. Regresa *false*.

---

Esta respuesta es una traducción de [mi respuesta a la misma pregunta en el sitio ruso](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431663/176684).

Answer (score 51):

La diferencia es que == primero intenta convertir los tipos antes de compararlos. El operador === no, hace una comparación directa aunque siempre retorna falso si los tipos son diferentes. [fuente (en inglés)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

ej:

```
1 == "1" // verdadero    
1 === "1" // falso
'' == 0 // verdadero
'' === 0 // falso
```

Estos gráficos quizá puedan ayudarte a visualizar la diferencia:

#### Operador '=='

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Operador '==='

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

([fuente de las imágenes](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/))

Answer (score 39):

Efectivamente `==` compara valor, mientras que `===` compara también tipo. Por ejemplo.

```
"1" == 1 // true
"1" === 1 // false
null == undefined // true
null === undefined // false
```

Puedes leer los detalles técnicos (en inglés) en [Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

`undefined` es una palabra reservada y se usa sin comillas.

Answer (score 31):

No exactamente. Es verdad que el operador `===` compara el tipo y el valor, sin hacer conversiones como haría el operador `==`. Sin embargo eso solo es cierto para tipos de valor. En los tipos por referencia lo que hace es comprobar que es el mismo objeto, no basta con que sea del mismo tipo y valor. Así que `===` sería un operador de identidad, al contrario que `==`.

Por ejemplo:

```
var a = { x: 1, y: 2 };
var b = { x: 1, y: 2 };
var c = a;

a === b  // false
a === c  // true
```

El caso de las cadenas funcionaría como un tipo de valor, a no ser que usaras el constructor `String`, que sería un tipo de referencia.

Señalar también que el operador `==` no es transitivo en algunas conversiones. Por ejemplo:

```
'' == '0'  // false
0 == ''    // true
```

Dada la ambigüedad de este operador, se aconseja que se use el operador `===` siempre que sea posible.

En todo caso puedes echar un vistazo a [esta página](http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) que resolverá dudas respecto a ambos operadores. Ahí puedes comprobar entre otras cosas que `undefined == null` pero `undefined !== null`.

Comment: gracias guillermo! lo que no acabo de entender es porque `a === b` es `false`....

Comment: Al ejemplo de transitividad le falta un caso: `'0' == 0 // true` (y mover el primer caso al último lugar)

Comment: @JordiCastilla eso ocurre porque JavaScript tiene dos maneras diferentes de comparar: en el caso de las primitivas (ej: int, string) se compara el valor, mientras que en el caso de los objetos (ej: date, array, u objetos definidos por el usuario) lo que se compara es la referencia y lo que se comprueba es que estén en la misma posición de memoria. Por eso cuando se compara `a` con `c` el resultado es `true`.

Comment: @JordiCastilla `a === b` es `false` porque `a` y `b` no apuntan al mismo objeto... apuntan a objetos diferentes cuyas propiedades da la casualidad de que tienen los mismos valores

Comment: Vale mencionar que `a == b` también es `false`.

Answer (score 15):

Bien sencillo

`==` es igualdad de valor y no de tipo.
`===` es igualdad de valor y tipo.

```js
 console.log("1 == '1   =>", 1 == '1')  // true
 console.log("1 === '1' =>", 1 === '1') // false, ya que uno es un string.
 console.log("1 === 1   =>", 1 === 1)   // son iguales
```

Answer (score 10):

Ya te han contestado correctamente la pregunta, pero me gustaría hacer un comentario en lo que parece ser tu problema (yo también empece con java y hay ciertas cosas que javascript facilita).

Una variable puede tener 2 estados, "undefined" o tener algo, null como en SQl es un tipo de valor, es decir que si tu variable tiene null esta definida y tiene algo, nada pero algo :P , undefined quiere decir que tu variable no ha sido definida, es curioso ese hecho sobre todo por que null == undefined responde true.

Ahora cuando tu buscas un elemento con js y no lo encuentra (por ejemplo document.getElementById("inpt")) su valor es null, en el caso que si lo encuentre preguntas por su value y en caso de no tenerlo te responde "".

La parte interesante es que con un simple if resuelves mucho.

```
var una,dos = null,tres =[],cuatro = 1;

if(noexisto) //es undefinided, saca error por que estas preguntando por ella
if( typeof notoy == "undefined") //es la manera correcta de preguntar si una variable no ha sido definida
if(una)//false pero no saca error por que implicitamente tiene un null
if(una == null) //es lo mismo que la anterior
if(dos) //false pero no saca error
if(tres) //true por que contiene un array, vacio pero es algo
if("")//false por que esta vacio
if(cuatro)//tiene algo por tanto es true
```

Answer (score 5):

En caso de no transpilar tu código JS (con Babel por ejemplo) la operación "==" es más rápida que la comprobación de tipo con "===" por lo tanto si tu código va a ser útilizado en muchas ocasiones (es parte de la arquitectura o alguna librería) es preferible usar "==" teniendo en cuenta que no vas a pasar un filtro de tipo. En el resto de ocasiones (la gran mayoría) es mejor utilizar la comprobación de tipos con "===" para evitar resultados inesperados.

Comment: Voy a aportar un poco más de verdad sobre la comparación de "==" y "===". Es sorprendente pero si haces unas pruebas de rendimiento la triple comparación es un 10% más rápida en la mayoría de casos que la doble. También, en el caso de comparar un "number" con un "string" que debemos transformar a "number" para poder realizar la comparación, el proceso se alarga unas 20 veces.

 
if ( +"1" === 1) {
    // Código 
}

Por lo tanto, para evitar grandes problemas de rendimiento es siempre recomendable usar "===" en todos los casos para forzarnos a escribir mejor código y respetar los tipos.

Answer (score 2):

Aclaremos conceptos:

- Toda variable en JavaScript tiene un **tipo** y un **valor**.
- En JavaScript existe algo llamado [coerción](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/coercion). La coerción es una conversión automática (e implícita) que realiza el motor de JavaScript en un intento de operar con valores de diferente tipo. Por ejemplo:

```js
const valor1 = '5';
const valor2 = 9;
let suma = valor1 + valor2;
console.log(suma);
```

Como valor1 es de tipo *string* y valor2 es de tipo *number*, JavaScript lleva a cabo la conversión automática del segundo valor en un intento de poder realizar la suma. De esta manera, el valor de la variable `suma` será de tipo *string*:

```
'59'
```

**CONCLUSIÓN**

El operador `==` compara dos valores sin tener en cuenta el tipo. Es decir, efectua coerción y entonces compara. Si los valores son iguales tras la conversión, devuele el valor `true`.

El operador `===` en cambio devuelve `true` solo en el caso en el que valor y tipo coincidan.

*Aclaración: esto solo aplica a los 6 tipos primitivos.*