# Cannot convert undefined or null to object en Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validación

Estoy comparando un arreglo que me llega de una consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
var data = response['return']; // Aquí se almacena el arreglo
var tableHead = '<tr>';
//Aquí comparo el arreglo para validar si esta vacío o indefinido o null

if(data === null || data === 'undefined' || data === ''){

  //Quiero imprimir este mensaje en el tbody de la tabla que estoy armando
  $tblReport.find('tbody').html('No hay datos disponibles');
}else{

//Aquí hago todo lo que necesito para formar mi tabla
 Object.keys(data[0]).each(function(prop){
  if(prop !== 'id_land' && prop !== 'id_product'){
    tableHead += '<th>'+prop+'</th>';
  }

 });
}
```

El código funciona muy bien, me arma la tabla con los datos, pero cuando hay un dato que no exista según la consulta, no hace la validación del "if", sino que directamente va al else, y obviamente me da error porque estoy solicitando los keys del arreglo para formar la tabla, y para evitar eso hago esa validación de que si el arreglo viene vacío me muestre el mensaje en el cuerpo de la tabla.

No entiendo si es que estoy haciendo mal las comparaciones, ya que he intentado lo siguiente y no me funciona:

```
if(typeof(data) === null || typeof(data) === 'undefined' || typeof(data) === ''){

      //Quiero imprimir este mensaje en el tbody de la tabla que estoy armando
      $tblReport.find('tbody').html('No hay datos disponibles');
    }else{

    //Aquí hago todo lo que necesito para formar mi tabla
     Object.keys(data[0]).each(function(prop){
      if(prop !== 'id_land' && prop !== 'id_product'){
        tableHead += '<th>'+prop+'</th>';
      }

     });
    }
```

o también:

```
if(data === null || data === 'undefined' || data === ''){

          //Quiero imprimir este mensaje en el tbody de la tabla que estoy armando
          $tblReport.find('tbody').html('No hay datos disponibles');

return null;
        }else{

        //Aquí hago todo lo que necesito para formar mi tabla
         Object.keys(data[0]).each(function(prop){
          if(prop !== 'id_land' && prop !== 'id_product'){
            tableHead += '<th>'+prop+'</th>';
          }

         });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas a tener en cuenta.

`undefined` no va entre comillas, es una palabra reservada.

```
> var data
> data === "undefined"
< false
> data === undefined
< true
```

Sin embargo `typeof`, si retorna la cadena "undefined"...

```
> typeof data
< "undefined"
> typeof data === "undefined"
< true
> typeof data === undefined
< false
```

Confuso no? pues si, un poco, es una de las features un poco retorcidas de javascript, ademas fijate en esta [tabla de verdades](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/333/25) como se comportan los operadores `===` y `==`. El operador `==` puede dar algunas veces falsos positivos dependiendo de los datos.

Por otro lado, `typeof null` retorna "object". Es algo heredado desde las primeras versiones de javascript y no hay mucho que hacerle. Por ello no es muy util.

Lo mas simple seria usar

```
if (data) { 
   // no es null, ni undefined. 

} else {
   // es null o undefined, poner mensaje de "no hay datos"

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta estaba confundido con las comparaciones

Answer (score 2):

## Resumen de == y === para validar vacíos

- `!a` implica que a puede ser: `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `0`, `""` (la cadena vacía)
- `a == false` no es lo mismo que `!a`, porque `[]` y `"0"` son `== false` pero no usando `!a`
- `a == null` implica que a puede ser: `null`, `undefined`
- `a === null` implica que a puede ser: `null`

## Probando

Para ver cómo funciona conviene hacer algunas pruebitas, por ejemplo:

```
[null, undefined, false, 0, '', [], {}, "0", true, 1].forEach(function(valor){
    console.log('el valor',JSON.stringify(valor));
    if(!valor)          console.log('!');
    if(valor == false)  console.log('==false');
    if(valor === false) console.log('===false');
    if(valor == null)   console.log('==null');
    if(valor === null)  console.log('===null');
    if(valor == 0)      console.log('==0');
    console.log('**********');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione en el if donde estaba haciendo la comparación en lugar de "===" puse "==", así:

```
if(data == null || data == 'undefined' || data == ''){

 $tblReport.find('tbody').html('No hay datos disponibles');

}
```

Lo que leí es que Javascript al hacer esto hace que los valores sean comparables y con "===" es mas estricto con las comparaciones Saludos!

Comment: Creo que deberías solucionarlo a la inversa. Usualmente en javascript el uso del `==` no es recomendado. En lugar de usar `data == 'undefined'` deberías usar `if (data)` que te da el mismo resultado para las tres comparaciones. Lee http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/

Comment: Si tienes razón, muchas gracias Saludos!