# Problema con los operadores de desigualdad. No retornan el valor boleano esperado

Tags: javascript

Primera vez que programo. Tengo un problema, usando un operador de desigualdad no puedo retornar el valor booleano esperado, ¿qué opinan?

```
function sonMedioHermanos (hijo1, hijo2) {

    return tienenLaMismaMadre !== tienenElMismoPadre;

    function tienenLaMismaMadre (hijo1, hijo2) {
        return madreDe(hijo1) === madreDe(hijo2);
    }

    function tienenElMismoPadre (hijo1, hijo2) {
        return padreDe(hijo1) === padreDe(hijo2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido @Joaquin a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: por favor lee [ask], edita tu pregunta y se mas claro con lo que intentas hacer

Comment: También considera usar == en vez de ===

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez ¿por qué debería considerar eso?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Imagina que sus funciones crean un objeto y lo devuelven, como no ha dado ese código es una posibilidad que el comparador estricto no de el resultado que espera

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez en ese caso un operador == o === daría igual, ¿no?

Comment: Gracias, ahora edito la pregunta. Se supone que deberia devolver false si ambas proposiones son iguales, y true si son distintas. Como un operador XOR

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/337

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Las llaves no están mal puestas para ese escenario concreto, pero sí es raro definir esas funciones de manera anidada (podría interesar reusarlas)

Comment: @PabloLozano tienes razón. No me había fijado bien.

Answer (score 2):

Te falta usar los parámetros, declaraste dos funciones pero no las estás llamando correctamente:

```
function sonMedioHermanos(hijo1, hijo2) {

    return tienenLaMismaMadre(hijo1, hijo2) !== tienenElMismoPadre(hijo1, hijo2);

    function tienenLaMismaMadre(hijo1, hijo2) {
        return madreDe(hijo1) === madreDe(hijo2);
    }

    function tienenElMismoPadre(hijo1, hijo2) {
        return padreDe(hijo1) === padreDe(hijo2);
    }

}
```