# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre == y ===?

Tags: javascript

Recientemente he comenzado a programar en javascript y he observado que en algunos ejemplos se usa `==` y en otros `===`

¿Existe alguna razón por la qué no se use siempre uno de los dos en concreto?

Comment: Te recomiendo ver este [articulo:Diferencias entre == y === (comparaciones en JavaScript)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/331/diferencias-entre-y-comparaciones-en-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El simbolo `==` se usa para evaluar el valor, mientras que el `===` evalua valor y tipo. Por seguridad, te aconsejo que te acostumbres a usar siempre el `===`.