# Cargar dato de un input a una variable

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo varios input de tipo texto y quiero que lo que se escriba en ellos se guarde mediante el click de un boton para que luego pueda acceder a el. Es decir una vez que se aprieta el boton se guarda el nombre de la serie la descripcion las temporadas y los capitulos, informacion que podre acceder luego mediante un menu.

En el codigo html tengo esto:

```
Nombre
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="texto" placeholder="Nombre" minlength="1" maxlength="30" id="Serie">
              <br>
              Descripcion
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="texto" placeholder="Descripcion" minlength="1" maxlength="30" id="Descripcion">
              <br>
              Cantidad de temporadas
              <br>
              <input type="number" name="texto" size="2" min="1" max="30" id="Temporadas">
              <br>
              Capitulos por temporada
              <br>
              <input type="number" name="texto" size="2" min="1" max="30" id="Capitulos">
              </p>
              <p>
              <button type="button" id="botonAgregar"> Agregar/Actualizar </button>
```

En el codigo javascript tengo:

```
window.addEventListener("load",inicio);

function inicio(){
    document.getElementById("botonAgregar").addEventListener("click", agregarSerie);

function agregarSerie() {
    let nombreSerie=document.getElementById("Serie").value;
    let descripcion=document.getElementById("Descripcion").value;
    let temporadas=Number(document.getElementById("Temporadas").value);
    let capitulos=Number(document.getElementById("Capitulos").value);
    if(nombreSerie!=""){
        let serie=new Serie(nombreSerie,descripcion,temporadas,capitulos);
        let ok=sistema.agregarSerie(serie);
        if(ok){
            alert("Se guardó");
            cargarCorresponde()
            cargarLista();
            cargarCombo();
        }
        else{
            alert("Nombre repetido")
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("Ingrese un nombre");
    }
}
```

Agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene varios problemas. A continuación te menciono un par de ellos que corresponden al JavaScript:

1. la función `inicio`, debería cerrar su bloque de código antes de la declaración de la función `agregarSerie`

Esta parte es incorrecta. ya que la expresión de la que se habla tiene un `!=` en lugar de un `=`

> 2. la expresión que has incluido en el `if` es una asignación cuando debería ser una comparación.
>
>     En JavaScript :
>
>     - el operador `=` se usa para asignar una valor o un objeto a una variable
>     - hay dos operadores de comparación de igualdad `==` y `===`

Para ayudar a los lectores de tu código y a tí mismo pon espacios en blanco antes y después de cada operador así como también antes y después de cada `{` y cada `}`

3. sistema no está declarado así que ok devolverá `undefined` el cuál es un `falsy` así que el bloque de `if(ok)` no se va a ejecutar.

Relacionado

- [Diferencias entre == y === (comparaciones en JavaScript)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/331/65)

Comment: ya hice los cambios que me sugeriste pero cuando aprieto el boton agregar solo funciona si no escribi ningun nombre. Pero cunado intento agregar los datos no pasa nada y nose cual es el error que tengo

Comment: Recién me doy cuenta que la expresión if tiene un operador `!=` en lugar de un `=`, perdona. Para ayudar a los lectores de tu código pon espacios en blanco antes y después de cada operador así como también antes y después de cada `{` y cada `}`