# Que igualdad es mejor usar == o ===

Tags: javascript

Buenas a todos estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y me tope con una clase en la cual explican las dos igualdades `==` & `===` queria saber si alguna es mejor que la otra o es situacional, muchas gracias.

Comment: En realidad depende el nivel de exigencia que quieres tener al momento de realizar comparaciones entre datos. Si usas sólo 2, significa que estás comparando si un valor es igual a otro y no diferenciando el tipo de dato por ejemplo, como lo haces si usas 3 signos

Comment: Se considera buena práctica el uso del tripe igual (https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq) ya que el doble igual puede dar lugar a confusión para algunos casos. De hecho, herramientas de calidad de código como ESLint que he enlazado añaden reglas para avisar de que es preferible el triple igual.

Comment: Tal como dice @ordago, no vale la pena utilizar la doble igualdad. De hecho, como bien menciona, casi todos los sistemas de *linting* te marcarán los `==` como error para que pongas `===`. Deberías siempre hacerlo incluso sin plugins como ESLint, pues es una muy buena práctica. Al final, en lenguajes tan *poco estrictos* como JS, es mejor siempre estar seguro de que una comparación es exactamente lo que necesitamos que sea :)

Comment: No hay una mejor que otra, son diferentes y por lo tanto, usar una u otra dará un resultado diferente según los operandos que estás comparando. Asi que no se trata de cuál es mejor, sino de cuál se puede o se debe usar según el caso. Saludos

Comment: Revisa este enlace en donde alguien pregunto Diferencias entre == y ===  (comparaciones en JavaScript) https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/331/107347